# rvm not installing ruby-2.2; Error running '__rvm_make -j4'

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, cocoapods, rvm

When I try to download Cocoapods, it says:

```
XXXX: ~ XXX$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Password:XX
ERROR: Error install cocoapods:
minitest requires Ruby version ~> 2.2.
```

Then I try every way to install ruby but it gives me this:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file https://rvm_io.global.ssl.fastly.net/binaries/osx/10.11/x86_64/ruby-2.2.5.tar.bz2
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
ruby-2.2.5 - #configure
ruby-2.2.5 - #download
ruby-2.2.5 - #validate archive
ruby-2.2.5 - #extract
ruby-2.2.5 - #validate binary
Libraries missing for ruby-2.2.5: __rvm_ls. Refer to your system manual for installing libraries
Mounting remote ruby failed with status 10, trying to compile.
Checking requirements for osx.
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/vishaljayakumar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.5, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.5 - #downloading ruby-2.2.5, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.5 - #extracting ruby-2.2.5 to /Users/vishaljayakumar/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.5.....
ruby-2.2.5 - #applying patch /Users/vishaljayakumar/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.5/fix_installing_bundled_gems.patch.
ruby-2.2.5 - #applying patch /Users/vishaljayakumar/.rvm/patches/ruby/2.2.5/openssl3.patch.
ruby-2.2.5 - #configuring......................................................-
ruby-2.2.5 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.2.5 - #compiling........................................................|
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/vishaljayakumar/.rvm/log/1581558007_ruby-2.2.5/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

What do I do?
I have done literally every solution here and it doesn't work:
[Github Error Page](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4484)

Let me just name some of them just for you to see.

- rvm get head
- rvm mount -r https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.3/ruby-2.3.8.tar.bz2
- rvm get stable; rvm reload; rvm install "ruby-2.2.X"
- anything to do with openssl(I have no idea what it is)
- rvm install ruby-2.6.5 --with-openssl-dir='{directory of openssl}
- sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
- rvm install 2.6.4
- brew install homebrew/portable-ruby/portable-openssl
- rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=/usr/local/opt/portable-openssl/

Please give me a solution that is not in here(or one of the above).

I am a little desperate as I have wasted a lot of time on these commands!

I am free to any answers or comments!!!!!

Comment: Looks like a ruby version issue for the dependency gem.Can you add more details like the ruby version, current ruby version etc.Looks like you are rvm for for managing ruby. To upgrade to a specific version in rvm first you need to install the version using rvm install 2.4.1 and then switch to the version.

Comment: How do you switch to the version?